# Get a document modifiedBy in JAVA with RestApi

Tags: list, rest, column, java

As you can see in images, I have some folder in my document library.  I wanna reach  the files in the folder and take the "`modifiedby`" column and change it with java-rest api.

I can reach the file like this:

```
https://siteUrl/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('Shared%20Documents/abcFolder')/Files('test.docx')
```

or library items, but I couldn't reach columns.

Do you know how I can get the columns value and change it?

[image: document library]

[image: columns]

EDIT

I think this one can be but if you have better idea or you know how I change modifiedby title in java please help me.

```
https://siteUrl/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('Shared%20Documents/abcFolder')/Files(test.docx')?$select=ModifiedBy/Title&$expand=ModifiedBy
```

Answer (score 0):

`ModifiedBy` references a user. The `Title` is the display name of the user and can not be modified using the client api.

[The docs state:](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/work-with-user-profiles-in-sharepoint)

> Not all functionality that you find in the
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles assembly is available from client
>   APIs. For example, you have to use the server object model to create
>   or change user profiles because they're read-only from client APIs
>   (except the user profile picture).